# How to store unknown number of images into the MySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I am creating multivendor ecommerce application using JAVA in android studio.
I wanted to create a database to store products added by the sellers. Now I wanted to store images uploaded by the sellers in the database and I know very well how to that.
But the problem is that I don't know how many image the seller is going to upload. Sometimes he uploads 1 sometimes 2 or 3 or 4 and so on. Can anybody tell me how to create a code and database table to upload unknown number of images into the database ?

Comment: *store images uploaded by the sellers in the database* Not recommended. Store them in the filesystem, and complete pathnames in the table.

Comment: Dont understand the problem. Everytime the user uploads an image you put it in the database. What else?

Comment: @Akina  Yes I know that and I am doing exactly what you said . What I am asking here is that how to make a database table if the no images uploaded by the seller is unknown . I don't know how many images he/she is going to upload .

Comment: Use a separate table to store the images and have a foreign key for the product?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat how to do that ?

Comment: If the amount of images per user is above 1 then you must create a table where you'd store images filenames, and add a column which refers to a row in users table. Common 1:N relation.

Comment: @blackapps I don't know the number of images user will upload .Its not fixed.

Comment: Well what does it matter? As everytime the user uploads an image you put it in the database. Today. Tomorro. Everytime.

Comment: See article: [*What Is a One-to-Many Relationship in a Database?*](https://vertabelo.com/blog/one-to-many-relationship/)

Answer (score 2):

If the user can upload multiple images, store them in a separate table

## product

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A |
| 2 | Product B |

## product_image

| product | image_path | sort_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | /path/to/image.jpg | 1 |
| 2 | /path/to/image-1.jpg | 1 |
| 2 | /path/to/image-2.jpg | 2 |
| 2 | /path/to/image-3.jpg | 3 |

Comment: I’m not sure the `sort_order` column helps here. Seems like a distraction, not mentioned in the problem statement.